# Navigation controller issue after presenting a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

im trying to present my view controller and it is presenting fine, but status bar color seems having some shadow, see the attachment

[image: Existing navigation bar or Status bar]

But i require

[image: Required design]

What is the reason for that shadow, i even tried changing the status bar style and added *view controller-based status bar appearance* to true and tried with false to nothing works, Help me with this.

Method used for navigation

```
func navigationMethod() {
    let pharmacyStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let copayCalculationVCidentifier = String(describing: ChangeViewCotnroller.self)
    
    if let copayCalculationViewController = pharmacyStoryboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: copayCalculationVCidentifier, creator: { coder in
        
        let copayCalculationVC = ChangeViewCotnroller(coder: coder)
        return copayCalculationVC
    }) as? ChangeViewCotnroller {
        
        present(copayCalculationViewController, withModelStyle: .automatic, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be coming from the background color of your root window. I think that should default to black, but perhaps you are setting it to grey somewhere (e.g. a scene delegate method). If you capture the view hierarchy in Xcode you might be able to identify the cause by exploring the view hierarchy.

Comment: agree with @GeoffHackworth . you just have to check your view hierarchy. you can set UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .black

Comment: That's not a "shadow" ... it's the top of the scaled-down view of the presenting controller. If you slowly drag down the presented controller, it should be obvious.

Comment: @DonMag that was my guess as well, but the top of the presenting controller is also visible in the second image, which stands for his desired result. I guess the question is not clear enough as of now, OP should specify what he meant for "shadow".